# Looking for a birthdate Range in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I am looking for a birthdate range of march 21 to April 20, and the year doesn't matter. and it seems that when i search other months and date are coming out.

```
select * from AllStudentInfo Where 
((MONTH(birthDate) >= 3 and day(birthDate) >= 21)
OR
(MONTH(birthDate) <= 4 and day(birthDate) <= 20))
AND
(BGRStatus = 'S' OR BGRStatus = 'SL')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chances are that you want to discover up & coming dates. In any case, you can create a virtual date as follows:

```
SELECT DATEFROMPARTS (2017,month(birthDate),day(birthDate) as birthday
FROM AllStudentInfo
```

In this case, you can use:

```
SELECT *
FROM AllStudentInfo
WHERE DATEFROMPARTS (2017,month(birthDate),day(birthDate)
    BETWEEN '2017-03-21' AND '2017-04-20';
```

The year `2017` is arbitrary. The point is that the dates in the `BETWEEN` clause are in the same year.

Using more modern techniques, you can combine it as follows:

```
WITH cte AS(
    SELECT *,DATEFROMPARTS (2017,month(birthDate),day(birthDate) as birthDay
    FROM AllStudentInfo
)
SELECT * FROM cte WHERE birthDay BETWEEN '2017-03-21' AND '2017-04-20';
```

The `cte` is a **Common Table Expression** which is an alternative to using a sub query.

Here is an alternative which is closer to the spirit of the question. You can use the `format` function to generate an expression which is purely month & day:

```
format(birthDate,'MM-dd')
```

The `MM` is MSSQL’s way of saying the 2-digit month number, and `dd` is the 2-digit day of the month.

This way you can use:

```
format(birthDate,'MM-dd') BETWEEN '03-21' AND '04-20'
```

Again as a CTE:

```
WITH cte AS(
    SELECT *,format(birthDate,'MM-dd') as birthDay
    FROM AllStudentInfo
)
SELECT * FROM cte WHERE birthDay BETWEEN '03-21' AND '04-20';
```

You should get the same results, but the year is completely ignored.

Comment: i'm looking for everyone's birthday that is happening from March-21 to April 20. So i can't have my year inputted in. as if i do input, other months data will appear as long as they have a condition of BGR = 'S' or BGR = 'SL'

Comment: @GiveChance That’s the point. This expression creates a new date for the current year.

Comment: just do the same method DATEFROMPARTS (year(getdate()),03,21) and DATEFROMPARTS (year(getdate()),04,20)

Comment: okay so i can't look for any years and the birthdate is from 03,21 to 04,20?

Comment: @GiveChance I’ve modified the answer to provide an alternative solution which doesn’t use the year.

Answer (score 0):

Switch your statement to `AND`

Like so

```
select * from AllStudentInfo Where 
((MONTH(birthDate) >= 3 and day(birthDate) >= 21)

AND --Make the change here

(MONTH(birthDate) <= 4 and day(birthDate) <= 20))
AND
(BGRStatus = 'S' OR BGRStatus = 'SL')
```

Using `OR` you are querying anything that is in that date range OR that month range. And therefore,  you would get results from other every months.

Comment: If i have change to AND there is no DATA is displayed. 
Although, i know there is student where birthdate is at 03/26

Comment: i have a data consist of 1999-03-26 , and BGRStatus is S but my data is not displaying if i am using the changes. i tried with AND as well but there is no data.